# How to React Performance Optimize Re-Renders With Timer?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm at a bit of a loss here for what to do and would love some recommendations.

I have a quizzing app that has a timer for a question. The parent contains the timer object which uses a callback to set the number of seconds remaining like so:

```
   const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState<number>(null);
   const timer = React.useRef<Timer>(new Timer({duration: 10, callback: i => setSeconds(i)}));

   ...

   return (
      <Context value={seconds}>
       ...

   )
```

The parent passes the seconds around to the descendants through a context because a child and grandchild both need access to the number of seconds remaining to show a timer.

The problem is that the update interval is every .1 seconds, and as a result the children and all subsequent descendants rerender which is a huge issue.

Is there a way that I can only have only the things that rely on the timer rerender?

I have all of my components wrapped in React.useMemo and am accessing the seconds with React.useContext.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the update interval is every .1 seconds, and as a result the children and all subsequent descendants rerender which is a huge issue.

This isn't entirely true. Only the specific [context consumers](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) will re-render based on `value` changes.

> Is there a way that I can only have only the things that rely on the timer rerender?

Aside from using Context, Yes there is another way.

1. Extract a `TimerComponent` from your context.
2. Use `redux` to dispatch `onTimerChange` action from your `TimerComponent`

```
// in mapDispatchToProps
updateTimer = (duration) => {
  dispatch({ action: 'TIMER_UPDATED', payload: { duration }});
}

// In reducer
case 'TIMER_UPDATED':
  const duration = action.payload.duration;
  return { ...state, duration };
```

3. Have the corresponding "consumer" component listen to `duration` prop in store.

```
mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    duration: state.duration;
  }
}
```

4. Every change in `duration` will cause the "consumer" component to re-render.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.duration !== this.props.duration) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

or pass `duration` to child

```
render() {
  const { duration } = this.props;
  return <SomeItem duration={duration} />;
}
```

Comment: Is this possible to do with using only functional components (and hooks), useEffect, and useReducer, rather than redux?

Comment: yes. replace `redux` with how `useReducer` works. `TimerComponent` can be a functional component.